# Select only two decimal places without rounding up

Tags: powershell

I want to select only two decimal places without rounding up.

```
$d = 123000.1264
'{0:f2}' -f $d
```

Result: `123000,13`, but I need the result `123000,12`

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

```
[Math]::Truncate(123000.1264 * 100) / 100
```

does it.

> 123000.1264 * 100 = 12300012.64
>   [Math]::Truncate(12300012.64) = 12300012
>   12300012 / 100 = 123000.12

You should use the [decimal] type for numbers when you need to preserve the accuracy of the fractional part, e.g.

```
$d = [decimal]123000.1264
```

and then [Math]::Truncate will use its [decimal overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx) to give a decimal, and a decimal divided by an integer (or a double) will give a decimal result.

Of course, there is more than one way to interpret "up": it could mean increase in value (3 > -5) *or* increase in magnitude (|-5| > |3|). If you need the former, then use [Math]::Floor (which converts -1.1 -> -2.0) instead of [Math]::Truncate (which converts -1.1 -> 1.0).